# Python unittest to test all instances in setUp have a unique number in an attribute?

Tags: python, python-unittest

I'm writitng tests to test a hypothetical list of songs in a database.

These Song instances and their attributes will be individually tested in later tests and I believe using setUp is a good way to stop repition:

```
class TestSong(unittest.TestCase):

def setUp(self):
    self.song001 = Song("Shake It Off", "Taylor Swift","2000", "Pop", 150)
    self.song002 = Song("Stronger", "Kelly Clarkson","2000", "Pop", 145)
    self.song003 = Song("I Will Survive", "Gloria Gaynor","1970", "Disco", 140)
```

etc....

I want to test that all the instances created for the tests have songID and that they are unique, the songID will just be an incrementing class variable to begin with set in **init** (so it should be...), but that could change later.

So i think I want to be able to add all setUp instances to a list, and then call that list in my  test_songID_unique(self): further down, which will loop through the list of Songs and do a unique test on the list of songID attributes, then pass or fail based on that.

I'm struggling understanding a good way to add all setUp instances to a list without writing it out (which feels very very wrong).

Comment: Not sure I understand the question - you just want to be make a list out of your song variables? Why not put them into a list in the first place?

Comment: I think what i'm looking for is a way to group all the setUp instances i might make into a list. I could pre-define that list, which *is* what i'm doing, but the setUp instance might be added to, or removed, and I'd want that list to reflect that?  The list i'm writing felt dirty, and i'm fairly new to this, but couldn't find another way to setUp the tests with the data.

Comment: I don't really understand what you are meaning by "setUp instances" - I guess you mean the `Song` instances. Usually you test by either using some random samples (songs in your case) , which cover all relevant cases, or you you take the data from the real code, if that is needed. I'm not sure what you are doing with your test in this case. Maybe you have to describe or show the code that you want to test.

Answer (score 0):

I used pytest parameterized fixtures to solve this.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).